# ZF2 & Doctrine2 getServiceConfig factories connection function

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have factories for Doctrine in **Module.php** method **getServiceConfig()** :

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_cst' => new \DoctrineORMModule\Service\EntityManagerFactory('orm_cst'),
            'doctrine.connection.orm_cst' => function ($sm) {
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    return new \DoctrineORMModule\Service\DBALConnectionFactory('doctrine.entitymanager.' . $config['connection']);
                },
            'doctrine.configuration.orm_cst' => new \DoctrineORMModule\Service\ConfigurationFactory('orm_cst'),
            'doctrine.driver.orm_cst' => new \DoctrineModule\Service\DriverFactory('orm_cst'),
            'doctrine.eventmanager.orm_cst' => new \DoctrineModule\Service\EventManagerFactory('orm_cst'),
        ),
    );
}
```

I'm trying to get connection value from **config** and I'm getting the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DoctrineORMModule\Service\DBALConnectionFactory could not be converted to string in W:\domains\zf\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 939
```

It's ok if I'm not using function as array value:

```
'doctrine.connection.orm_cst' => new \DoctrineORMModule\Service\DBALConnectionFactory('orm_cst'),
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: What does `$config['connection']` hold.

Answer (score 1):

The `doctrine.connection` should return a configured `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`.

At the moment, you are incorrectly returning the *actual ZF2 factory instance* (`\DoctrineORMModule\Service\DBALConnectionFactory`) rather than using it to create the connection.

If you wish to keep the closure, you can just manually call the `createService()` method and it should work.

```
'doctrine.connection.orm_cst' => function ($sm) {
    $config = $sm->get('config');

    $key = 'doctrine.entitymanager.' . $config['connection'];
    $factory = new DBALConnectionFactory($key);

    // Manually call the createService method and the factory will then
    // return the Connection instance
    return $factory->createService($sm);
},
```

The other (preferred) option would be to extend the default Doctrine factory and define the configuration key within the factory itself, this way you have everything needed to create the connection in one place (which is really the idea behind using a factory).

If you are not using the above closure, it is also worth noting that by creating your service factories with `new` you are recreating every service factory on every request - This will have an unnecessary negative performance impact. The solution again would be to extend and/or wrap the Doctrine factories in your own custom factory and just use a string to reference them. The service manager will then be able to lazy load them.

```
'doctrine.connection.orm_cst' => 'MyModule\Factory\CstConnectionFactory',
```